MSAL Redirect Issue with Multiple iFrames in NestJS Application
I'm using azure/msal-node in my NestJS application to handle authentication. My application has a single authentication endpoint at /app, which constructs an authorization URL and redirects the user to https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize.
The application is embedded as two iframes: /app?page=a and /app?page=b. However, when attempting to authenticate through these iframes, I only receive a redirect for one of the pages, not both.
Here’s what I’m seeing:
The redirect to the MSAL authorization endpoint happens correctly for one iframe.
The other iframe does not trigger a redirect, resulting in a failure to authenticate for that page.
Questions:
Is there a known issue with MSAL when handling authentication in multiple iframes?
Are there specific configurations or strategies for ensuring that each iframe can successfully trigger its own authentication flow?
What best practices can be applied to handle authentication in an application embedded within iframes?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!
divided \app to \app1 and \app2  still facing same issue
